# mongodbrestore don't seem to restore all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

In dump/enron directory messages.bson and messages.medata.json fiels. It should restore 
120,477 documents.
I want to restore data from it.
I input command:

```
mongorestore -v --db enron --drop  dump/enron
```

After command is finished I get a messagee:
120477 objects found
don't know what to do with file [dump/enron/messages.metadata.json]

But in the collection message I see 112196 documents using:

```
db.messages.count()
```

Could you please tell me what's the problem with it?
The output of the command:

```
c:\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.5\bin>mongorestore -v  dump/enron/
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39 dump/enron/messages.bson
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39      going into namespace [enron.messages]
Tue Dec 11 14:17:39      file size: 396236668
                126878231/396236668     32%
                270206614/396236668     68%
                375698921/396236668     94%
                381433738/396236668     96%
                387378348/396236668     97%
                394626836/396236668     99%
120477 objects found
don't know what to do with file [dump/enron/messages.metadata.json]
```

What does the message: "don't know what to do with file [dump/enron/messages.metadata.json]" mean?

Answer (score 4):

**This should work:**

```
ssharma$ mongorestore -d enron --collection messages /dump/enron/messages.bson
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thu Mar  7 13:05:05 /dump/enron/messages.bson
Thu Mar  7 13:05:05     going into namespace [enron.messages]
Thu Mar  7 13:05:09         74234213/396236668  18% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:12         126614885/396236668 31% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:15         192098158/396236668 48% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:18         208083274/396236668 52% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:21         231816712/396236668 58% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:24         293564538/396236668 74% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:27         356071219/396236668 89% (bytes)
Thu Mar  7 13:05:30         379387449/396236668 95% (bytes)
120477 objects found
Thu Mar  7 13:05:32     Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "enron.messages", name: "_id_" }
ssharma$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
> use enron
switched to db enron
> db.messages.count()
120477
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the database and the collection when restoring the bson file.

It works for me like so:

```
$ mongodump -d mark --collection coll 
connected to: 127.0.0.1
DATABASE: mark   to     dump/mark
    mark.coll to dump/mark/coll.bson
         1000 objects
```

and

```
  $ mongorestore -d mark --collection newcoll dump/mark/
    connected to: 127.0.0.1
    Wed Aug 29 11:48:39 dump/mark/coll.bson
    Wed Aug 29 11:48:39      going into namespace [mark.newcoll]
    1000 objects found
```

Can you try -

```
mongorestore -d enron --collection messages /dump/enron/
```

Comment: But it copies data in correct collection, the issues is the number of documents are not correct. Why does it say: "120477 objects found"; but only 112196 after restoring. Before restoring there is not data in collection.

Comment: What does the message: "don't know what to do with file [dump/enron/messages.metadata.json]" mean?

Comment: It's hard to tell not having access to your data, however, the reduced number would suggest that some objects were not successfully imported. This seems to be due to corruption or an issue with the structure (which the message `don't know what to do` would appear to confirm). You could possibly try to [bsondump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bsondump/) the original bson file and analyse it for corruption. You can also increase the verbosity on the `mongorestore` with `-vvvvv` to see if anything more is logged.

Comment: It's very strange I have error on windows xp machine but it's ok on remove linux server.

Comment: I don't have an XP box handy but if you're doing something on Linux and it works but doesn't on XP, then it would appear to be a bug on XP. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using mongodb 2.05 on Windows machine and 2.2 on linux server.

Comment: Well, that's not a straight comparison. You should upgrade to 2.2.2 on Windows and compare the `restore` results then.

Comment: mongodb 2.2 doesn't supposrt windows xp.

Comment: Yep, I forgot that, sorry - it's as per [this SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5648). I'd recommend upgrading to the latest 2.0.x then as there were some Windows issues in 2.0.3/4/5.

Comment: version 2.2 is not supporting in Windows XP> On Window XP I have 32-bit mongodb 2.05, on server 64-bit 2.2.

Comment: I know it's not suported on XP, hat's why I said upgrade to the latest 2.0.x - "2.0", not "2.2".